# Can't compile sass files, have such error http://joxi.ru/4Ako9e9TMyY6DA

Tags: sass, gulp

Need your help, Can't compile sass files, have such error

```
[16:51:40] Finished 'serve' after 113 ms

events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
 Error: assets\sass\style.sass
undefined
    at options.error (C:\Users\Ростислав\Desktop\last\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:277:32)
```

style.sass have only @imports http://joxi.ru/5mdY3M3HvkYX42, tried to remove remove alternately, but it helps,when remove all imports

my gulp task

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('assets/sass/*.sass')
        .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'],
            cascade: false,
            remove: false
        }))
        .pipe(minifyCss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

Comment: If you compile directly with Sass, rather than via Gulp, do you still get an error?

Comment: Yes, i have such error :Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: IMB866 and UTF-8

Comment: Well, then there you got your problem reason: codification. Also, check how to handle errors, so you get feedback from the console and you dont break your task :)

Comment: I solve the problem, it was problem with  Node and russian name of user in system, and Node doesn't like it.Thank's everybody)

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with LibSass and directories with Cyrillic characters. This may also apply to other non-ASCII characters. Please try the gulp-sass beta for the patch:

```
npm install gulp-sass@beta
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. If this known issue is on a public bug tracker, it would help to have its address.